# In the People list, change from time span display to date display

Tags: users, entities

This is Drupal 7: when I am logged in as administrator and I click "People" to check the registered users, the default Drupal display is the "Member for", which displays a time span. For example: "2 min 10 sec" or "23 hours 24 min" or even "6 days 22 hours". How can I change that display to a "Member since" display that would show the date and time the user actually registered? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of an existing module that will do this but the following function in a custom module will do the trick:

```
function MYMODULE_form_user_admin_account_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Get the user IDs listed in the form
  $uids = array_keys($form['accounts']['#options']);

  // Since loading the user objects will incur overhead it would be best to get the
  // created data directly from the users table. It's a shame because this query has
  // already been run in user_admin_account(), but it's not saved anywhere that we can
  // easily pick it up.
  $sql = 'SELECT uid, created FROM {users} WHERE uid IN (:uids)';
  $created_data = db_query($sql, array(':uids' => $uids))->fetchAllKeyed();

  // Loop through the results and change the column data for the "Member for" column.
  foreach ($created_data as $uid => $created) {
    $form['accounts']['#options'][$uid]['member_for'] = date('d/m/Y H:i', $created);
  }

  // Finally change the header to say "Member Since"
  $form['accounts']['#header']['member_for']['data'] = t('Member Since');
}
```

The only thing you might want to change is the date format...see PHP's [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function for all the available tokens

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try and update the status later on!

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to test your code. I have tried it yesterday and it works 100% as expected! Thanks a lot!